# jQuery Event handlers for Javascript functions

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, events, jquery-events

The question title is a bit obscure so let me explain.

A requirement that was only explained to me recently is the use of jQuery in my project. But it has been noted that my functions are fine as is and can be reused as long as they contain some jQuery.

So I'm exploring the world of event listeners for the first time (js side not in the HTML)

A standard Jquery `onclick` event:

```
referenceToElement.onclick = function () { alert('here'); };
```

One thing I notice is that the function doesn't actually have a name. Is there any clean way of doing something like:

```
referenceToElement.onclick = myOldJavascriptFunction();

function myOldJavascriptFunction()
{
    //blahblahblah
}
```

Is this good practice or is there a better way to do it. Will this even work now that I think of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the question is actually worth a downvote, since you could **easily** answer all those questions by searching, I'll give you a headsup.

That

```
referenceToElement.onclick = function () { alert('here'); };
```

is for sure no jQuery standard thing. It's pure Javascript, adding a property to a DOM reference, in this case an anonymous function. However, you basically asked two questions now.

- can we give that anonymous function a name ? => YES
- can we reference a function which is defined somewhere else ? => YES

To give it a name, we can just create a *named function expression* like this

```
referenceToElement.onclick = function myFunctionName() { alert('here'); };
```

To reference a function, we just pass in it's name

```
referenceToElement.onclick = myOldJavascriptFunction;
```

Finally, jQuery's syntax to add the same event listener would look like this:

```
$( referenceToElement ).click( myOldJavascriptFunction );
```

Comment: I did look. Most of the examples for event listeners either defined it within the html itself as an onclick, or defined the function manually as your second snippet of code shows. Where i was tripping up was actually the parentheses. If you still think its worth a downvote then go ahead.

Comment: +1 for the explanation.  Also, *named function expressions* don't work the way they're supposed to in IE8 and lower.

Comment: @OVERTUNE: I was just saying with a little efford that was an easy search, no offence!

Comment: @jAndy. Its overtone. And there as none taken. I was serious about the downvote. No malice or bad feelings on my end either way.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you were very nearly right:

```
referenceToElement.onclick = myOldJavascriptFunction;
```

Note the lack of parentheses. This passes a reference to the function to the `onclick` event. Also note that this is plain old JavaScript, not jQuery. The jQuery way of doing this is more like:

```
$(referenceToElement).click(myOldJavascriptFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first example there is plain and normal javascript, nothing to do with jQuery at all. If you were using jQuery, the line would look like this:

```
$(referenceToElement).click(function () { ... });
```

But in any case, it seems like you question is about anonymous functions. You can assign the function to a variable name, or use a function declaration and still reference that function by name:

```
function myFunction () { ... }

$(referenceToElement).click(myFunction);
```